# rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-install

Tags: ros, rosdep, rosdep-install, ros-fuerte, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I found there's something wrong with the installation of openni_kinect as I followed this website:http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect.

But when I typed rosmake openni_kinect --rosdep-install in the terminal of Ubuntu12.04, it displays rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-install. I have already checked on the internet, the answer seems to be http://answers.ros.org/question/38291/no-such-option-rosdep-install/.

I have tried but it still doesn't work!!!Looking for help!!!!
Thank you so much!

Lili

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39571/rosmake:-error:-no-such-option:---rosdep-install/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it seems that I should call rosdep install and rosmake seperately in fuerte:
After I type
rosdep install openni_kinect
rosmake openni_kinect

rather than
rosmake openni_kinect --rosdep-install
in the terminal.

It finally works!!!

---

Originally posted by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) with karma: 286 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-23**:
This is correct. The `rosmake --rosdep-install` option is no longer available in Fuerte. Use an explicit `rosdep install` command, instead.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the bottom of the [install page for fuerte](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu), you find these instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-pip

sudo easy_install -U rosinstall vcstools rosdep
```

After you run this, you will have rosdep. If you are on Ubuntu, you should be able to install openni_kinect with your package manager.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-openni-kinect
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1